# Enabling video mode with default camera

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I am making an app with 3 tab bars and camera function in the middle.
I am trying to let user tab the camera in tab bar and take videos/photos. I successfully coded so camera opens when the camera button in tab bar is pressed. When the camera opens, it is very different than apple's default camera. There is no option like changing modes of camera from photo to video.  The code I wrote is like below. Please help! Thank you.

```
 import UIKit

typealias PhotoTakingHelperCallback = UIImage? -> Void

class PhotoTakingHelper : NSObject {

/** View controller on which AlertViewController and UIImagePickerController are presented */
weak var viewController: UIViewController!
var callback: PhotoTakingHelperCallback
var imagePickerController: UIImagePickerController?

init(viewController: UIViewController, callback: PhotoTakingHelperCallback) {
    self.viewController = viewController
    self.callback = callback

    super.init()

    showPhotoSourceSelection()
}
func showImagePickerController(sourceType: UIImagePickerControllerSourceType) {
    imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePickerController!.sourceType = sourceType
    imagePickerController!.showsCameraControls == true
    imagePickerController!.navigationBarHidden == false
    imagePickerController!.toolbarHidden == false
    imagePickerController!.allowsEditing == true
    imagePickerController!.startVideoCapture() == true

    self.viewController.presentViewController(imagePickerController!, animated: true, completion: nil)


}

func showPhotoSourceSelection() {
    // Only show camera option if rear camera is available
    if (UIImagePickerController.isCameraDeviceAvailable(.Rear)) {
       self.showImagePickerController(.Camera)
    }


}

}
```

[image: It looks like a picture below.]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make the video option available you need to set the mediaTypes as follow:

```
imagePickerController!.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypesForSourceType(.Camera)!
```

Note: When setting boolean values you have to use single equal sign:

```
imagePickerController!.showsCameraControls = true
imagePickerController!.navigationBarHidden = false
imagePickerController!.toolbarHidden = false
imagePickerController!.allowsEditing = true
```

Comment: Thank you! It is solved! And thanks for pointing out the equal sign. I don't know why I wrote double equal signs.